# WolframAlpha API throws exception in Android but not console

Tags: java, android, api, wolframalpha

I'm building a simple calculator and I wanted to verify my calculations using a proven calculator, WolframAlpha but I'm having some consistency issues. I'm programming this to learn more about Android, Java and XML. Most of this code is taken directly from the WolframAlphaSample.java file and simplified to only return the 'pods' (information) we need.

In my ActivityMain.java I pass the function my editText:

```
Double wolframAnswer = WolframAlpha.queryInput(editLine.getText().toString());
```

In WolframAlpha.queryInput() my code looks like:

```
    public static double queryInput(String input)
    {
        WAEngine engine = new WAEngine();
        System.out.println("Wolfram Input: " + input);
        // These properties will be set in all the WAQuery objects created from this WAEngine.
        engine.setAppID(appid);
        engine.addFormat("plaintext");
        engine.addIncludePodID("DecimalApproximation");
        engine.addIncludePodID("Result");
        WAQuery query = engine.createQuery(); // Create the query.
        query.setInput(input); // Sets property of the query.
        double finalResult = 0.0;
        try {
            // This sends the URL to the Wolfram|Alpha server, gets the XML result
            // and parses it into an object hierarchy held by the WAQueryResult object.
            WAQueryResult queryResult = engine.performQuery(query);
            //System.out.println(((WAPlainText)(queryResult.getPods()[0].getSubpods()[0].getContents()[0])).getText());
            String unroundedResult;

            if (queryResult.isError()) 
            {
                return 1.0; // error
            } 
            else if (!queryResult.isSuccess()) 
            {
                return 2.0; // misunderstood
            }
            else if(queryResult.getPods().length == 1)
            { 
                unroundedResult = ((WAPlainText)(queryResult.getPods()[0].getSubpods()[0].getContents()[0])).getText();
                if (unroundedResult.endsWith("...")) // Remove trailing dots if really long number
                {
                    unroundedResult = unroundedResult.replaceAll("\\.\\.\\.", "");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                unroundedResult = ((WAPlainText)(queryResult.getPods()[1].getSubpods()[0].getContents()[0])).getText();
            }
            finalResult = Double.parseDouble(unroundedResult);
        } catch (WAException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalResult;
        }
}
```

When we run this from the console within WolframAlpha.java with a simple query (5+8) it works fine, if we run it from our Android App, which passes the exact same data, it catches and throws an exception. Any idea why we're seeing two different behaviours?

Small Note: Returning 1.0 and 2.0 isn't the best idea but was thrown in because I'm not sure how to return an error that isn't a double and I wanted to debug what was going on, it turned out it wasn't taking that path anyway but I left it here.

Comment: It would be very helpful to post a partial stack track.

Answer (score 2):

LogCat may be your best friend here. it probably has something to do with the android runtime, call an Async Task to handle HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected WAQueryResult doInBackground(String... urls) {

        WAQueryResult queryResult = engine.performQuery(query);

        return queryResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(WAQueryResult response) {
         if (queryResult.isError()) 
        {
            return 1.0; // error
        } 
        else if (!queryResult.isSuccess()) 
        {
            return 2.0; // misunderstood
        }
        else if(queryResult.getPods().length == 1)
        { 
            unroundedResult = ((WAPlainText)(queryResult.getPods()[0].getSubpods()[0].getContents()[0])).getText();
            if (unroundedResult.endsWith("...")) // Remove trailing dots if really long number
            {
                unroundedResult = unroundedResult.replaceAll("\\.\\.\\.", "");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            unroundedResult = ((WAPlainText)(queryResult.getPods()[1].getSubpods()[0].getContents()[0])).getText();
        }
        finalResult = Double.parseDouble(unroundedResult);
    }
}
```

If this do not work, try call the methods with Strings instead of WAQueryResult.